# Why is the tableViewCell getting unselected on coming back to the ViewController?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableView with custom cell in my ViewController, I select a cell and go to next ViewController.

However on coming back, the cells gets deselected automatically.

This is the first time I am seeing something like this.

I haven't written anything inside, viewDidAppear,viewWillAppear,viewDidDisappear or viewWillDisappear of the first ViewController that could do something like this.

I ran the code in simulator with slow animation to see what is happening.

While coming back, the cell is still selected but soon the selection goes away.

I put a break point inside setSelected:animated: method inside by customCell to backtrack whats calling it.

Here is what I see ...

[image]

Comment: Did you google is at all? `-setClearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear`

Comment: I had never used TableViewController before this.I was used to a plain VC implementing delegate and datasource. 

I found this behaviour weird and as soon as i put up the question I realised there is a call to UITableViewController's viewWillAppear which i checked and realised that it might be the default implementation there.
then this answer came otherwise I had over-ridden an empty viewWillAppear in UITableViewController subclass.

So I had no idea b4 that , what to google, I tried googling .
"tableViewCell getting unselected on coming back to the ViewController"
didn't work for me

Comment: instead I use to get 

"Deselecting the table view row when returning" on SO as the first link.
but thanks to this question, anyone Googling now, will get this question as the top result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a property of `UITableViewController`, set `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to NO

Comment: yeah.. I realised that. I always used plain ViewControllers with TableViews and was used to implementing datasource and delegate in the VC itself.
I practically never used UITableViewController at all.
So this was the first time we were using it and this felt weird.

Comment: fair enough, i do the same so i looked at UITableView first, I only checked the docs for UITableViewController because I saw it in the stack trace

Comment: Thats exactly what I did after I posted the screenshot and submitted the question.
my eyes went on tableVieaController viewWillAppear then I realized.. by then ur answer came followed by that downvote.